# fread: read until "end of line" (do not cut off lines)

Tags: php, file, fopen, fread

I would like to read a file until X bytes. But the last line should be NOT cut off like in my current code:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(! feof($file)) {
    $contents = fread($file,10000);
```

Right now, fread reads until 10000 bytes are reached. Then cuts the line off and creates a new file. The line basically is completely stores but is split into two files. I dont want do only stop and the end of a line.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: What you trying to achieve? Instead of fread use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) or [stream_get_line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php), and count the lines length with strlen. You could even use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then on a loop count chars etc.

Comment: I want to split a large file into smaller ones. If I do it line by line it takes days (~50 kb/sec). Thats why I need something like fread so I dont need to read and save every single line separately.

Comment: That's not how it works, it wont take days more like 1 second, you don't store each line in a new file you concatenate the lines and count then create your new file at char 10k, basically what I said above. What your doing cant be done with fread.

Comment: Do you have an example code? Or can you give me some expressions to search for? I dont know how this is called and which functions to use.

Comment: You can still use `fread()`, and fetch the remainder of the current line with `fgets()`.

Comment: How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(! feof($file)) {
    $contents = fread($file,$eachFileSize);
    $contents = $contents . fgets($file);
```

Can someone confirm this is the intended way (e.g. LawrenceCherone suggested)?